# rpm conditional dependency requirements

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm working on a piece of software just now that needs to run on a newer version of Redhat. It currently works fine on 6 and 7 but now needs to install and run on Redhat 8.

There is nothing really specific in the software that will stop it running on the newer OS version but i'm having a problem with the dependency requirements. The script that runs the software needs access to semanage (/usr/sbin/semanage). On Redhat 6 and 7 this was supplied by policycoreutils-python package and was given as a requirement argument when the rpm was built. From Redhat 8 onwards, the package has been renamed to policycoreutils-python-utils (see this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index), section 8.6.2).

From rpm 4.13, there is support for boolean dependencies (see [here](https://rpm.org/user_doc/boolean_dependencies.html)) which would make this an easy fix as I could just do something like `-R (policycoreutils-python or policycoreutils-python-utils)` but changing the rpm-build package from its current 4.8 version is a major pain as it's used by another team for another piece of software. I also need to keep it a distro independent rpm so can't have different versions of the rpm for newer versions of the OS.

So, my questions:

1) Is there some other way to have a conditional requirement in the spec file with the older rpm 4.8 version?

2) If I was to get approval to upgrade rpm to latest 4.15, is there likely to be any issue on target systems that have older rpm installed e.g. not understanding the conditional?

Update: The rpm will be built once on a RH 6 box and should work on RH 7 & 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## if you build one rpm for all platforms

You can depend on `semanage` itself:

```
Requires: /usr/sbin/semanage
```

`yum`, `dnf` or `rpm` should be smart enough to work that out.

## if you build each rpm on the corresponding target:

you can use the `%rhel_version` macros, see https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_cross_distribution_howto :

```
%if 0%{?rhel_version} < 800
Requires: policycoreutils-python
%else
Requires: policycoreutils-python-utils
%endif
```

Comment: This didn't work for me although reading the document I can't see why it won't. I had to use "%if 0%{?rhel} >= 8" instead as the "rhel_version" macro is not defined on my systems. Building the rpm on my local centos 6 VM, the output of rpm -qpR <rpm> on the three versions of Redhat I have always produces 'policycoreutils-python' as a dependency.

Comment: I think this way only works if the rpm is built on each of the different OS. I've updated the question to make it clear I was wanting one built RPM to support the 3 OS versions.

Comment: fantastic thanks. Do you know if that works with libraries too e.g. openssl changed to compat-openssl10 in RH 8. Needing a 'Requires' for /usr/lib64/libssl and /usr/lib64/libcrypto.

Comment: So it seems I can use a requirement on libssl.so.10. The only issue with this is it tries to pull the wrong architecture. e.g. Requires: libssl.so.10 tries to pull i686 version of compat-openssl10 but Requires: compat-openssl10 pulls x86_64

Comment: if you have a system where the right package is installed, you can run `rpm -q <package> --provides` to see  what this package provides, you can probably choose one of those provides as your requirement.